# Samsung Watchon like app for R-34SVC/48B3034SVC IR remote control

Tags: android

I am looking for a samsung watchon like app for [R-34SVC](http://www.matelecommandetv.com/Prix/R-34SVC-TELECOMMANDE-DE-10077.html).
This is a service remote control *(not the user remote control sold with the TV)* for acessing the [Service mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_mode) of the TV, so I would be able to diagnose the problem and mend it.

So is there an app which would perform like the samsung watchon *(by using the IR port of my tablet)* but for servicing activities? *(since samsung watchon are only for user remotes controls)*

Comment: Or if anyone has idea/link to a related private doc from Daewoo electronics, I would be glad to write the program myself.